# How do I limit JSON array output in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter

I have a JSON array. I need to limit it with some conditions in flutter and show it in Paginated Data Table widget.

Here is my JSON array:

```
var customers = [
  {
      'Customer_Code': '1001',
      'Customer_Name': 'Priston',
      'City': 'NewYork',
      'Enabled': true,
  },
  {
      'Customer_Code': '1002',
      'Customer_Name': 'Harold',
      'City': 'NewYork',
      'Enabled': true,
  },
  {
      'Customer_Code': '1003',
      'Customer_Name': 'Hohn',
      'City': 'London',
      'Enabled': true,
  },
  {
      'Customer_Code': '1004',
      'Customer_Name': 'Schwan',
      'City': 'London',
      'Enabled': false,
  },
  {
      'Customer_Code': '1005',
      'Customer_Name': 'Walter',
      'City': 'NewYork',
      'Enabled': false,
  },
];
```

And this is my code with flutter:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'json/test.dart';

class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  Testing({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TestingState createState() => _TestingState();
}

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {
  var dts = Dts();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: PaginatedDataTable(
          header: Text('Customers'), 
          columnSpacing: 10,
          columns: [
            DataColumn(label: Text('Row')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Customer Code')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Customer Name')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('City')),
          ],
          source: dts,
          rowsPerPage: 15,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Dts extends DataTableSource {

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    var post = customers[index];
    var i = index + 1;
    return DataRow.byIndex(index: index,cells: [
      DataCell(Text('$i')),
      DataCell(Text(post['Customer_Code'])),
      DataCell(Text(post['Customer_Name'])),
      DataCell(Text(post['City'])),

    ]);
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get rowCount => customers.length;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

And the result is this:

[image: JSON Array in paginated data table]

I need to limit it to customers with this condition :

`city = NewYork` and `Enabled = true`.

I don't know how to do it.

I used `customers` variable as my data table source and it displayed entire JSON array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart allows to filter a list using where.

I added this line and problem solved:

```
var newlst = customers.where((f) => f['City']=='NewYork' && f['Enabled']==true).toList();
```

Now the result is displayed in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of displayed result]